# Why rails is not generating a route helper for my 'match' route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

This is the two routes i declared in my config/routes.rb file :

```
  namespace :projects do
    match "proj_rapports_contributeur/select" => 'proj_rapports_contributeur#select', :via => :get
    match "proj_rapports_contributeur/generate/:id" => 'proj_rapports_contributeur#generate', :via => :get
  end
```

This is the resulting routes and helpers rails generate with `rake routes` :

```
projects_proj_rapports_contributeur_select_fr        /hierarchie/rapports_contributeur/selectionner(.:format)                                               projects/proj_rapports_contributeur#select {:locale=>"fr"}
projects_proj_rapports_contributeur_select_en        /en/projects/proj_rapports_contributeur/select(.:format)                                               projects/proj_rapports_contributeur#select {:locale=>"en"}

                                                     /hierarchie/rapports_contributeur/generer/:id(.:format)                                                projects/proj_rapports_contributeur#generate {:locale=>"fr"}
                                                     /en/projects/proj_rapports_contributeur/generate/:id(.:format)                                         projects/proj_rapports_contributeur#generate {:locale=>"en"}
```

I don't understand why rails didnt generate a route helper for the second route ?

Don't be surprised with the translated route. I'm using the gem 'rails-translate-routes'  to translate routes (Resource : https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes)

---

**=== UPDATE for FINAL ANSWER ===**

According to the answeer, for those wanting to know the end word, here it the routes I will be using :

```
  namespace :projects do

    get "proj_rapports_contributeur/select" => 'proj_rapports_contributeur#select'
    get "proj_rapports_contributeur/generate/:id" => 'proj_rapports_contributeur#generate', :as => 'proj_rapports_contributeur_generate'
  end
```

And these are the resulting helpers :

```
projects_proj_rapports_contributeur_select_fr GET    /hierarchie/proj_rapports_contributeur/selectionner(.:format)                                               projects/proj_rapports_contributeur#select {:locale=>"fr"}
projects_proj_rapports_contributeur_select_en GET    /en/projects/proj_rapports_contributeur/select(.:format)                                                    projects/proj_rapports_contributeur#select {:locale=>"en"}
projects_proj_rapports_contributeur_generate_fr GET    /hierarchie/proj_rapports_contributeur/generer/:id(.:format)                                                projects/proj_rapports_contributeur#generate {:locale=>"fr"}
projects_proj_rapports_contributeur_generate_en GET    /en/projects/proj_rapports_contributeur/generate/:id(.:format)                                              projects/proj_rapports_contributeur#generate {:locale=>"en"}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the route is not a simple route, it contains a parameter (in your case :id). In this case, you should specify the route name manually using `as`

```
match "proj_rapports_contributeur/generate/:id" => 'proj_rapports_contributeur#generate', :via => :get, :as => "your_route_name"
```

As a side note, replace `match` + `via` with the corresponding method name.

```
get "proj_rapports_contributeur/generate/:id" => 'proj_rapports_contributeur#generate'
```

It's shorter, and match is deprecated in Rails 4.

Comment: Thanks ! It's a shame we can not find any info on "get" nor on route-helpers with route using parameters in the official doc http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html